# Is this the simplest and most flexible solution to vertically aligning text within a block element?

Tags: css, layout, xhtml, html

I could be the first person to discover this (or at least document it on the web):

HTML:

```
<div>Vertically Aligned Text<span></span></div>
```

CSS:

```
div
{
    height: 100px; /* or whatever % etc. */
}

div > span
{
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It works because the code increases the line-height to 100% of its container, but I don't understand why setting `vertical-align: middle;` on the `<span></span>` affects the text.

I have not found this solution documented on the web, and it is simpler and more flexible than others that I have found. Plus it should work on all browsers from IE6 onwards (obviously replacing the child selector with something else).

To fit the question requirement, is this the simplest and most flexible solution to an age-old question?

Comment: Nice but only works if the text isn't borken over more than one line http://jsfiddle.net/aQNWp/

Comment: Had a similar result some time ago (http://jsfiddle.net/MJL3U/1/embedded/result/). @ChrisCannon: A "fiddlink" is a http://jsfiddle.net demonstration.

Comment: this is a fiddlink jsfiddle.net/aQNWp

Comment: @Dampsquid ahh well, good for buttons though if the width is fixed

Comment: @Chris - Yep, I'm sure it will come in handy

Comment: The line-height method usually makes assumption about font settings that are ultimately under the user's control and as mentioned gets real ugly when text wraps.

Comment: Ermm... I thought that using css e.g. font-size: 12px; fixes the font size so that it can't be enlarged with "text size larger" functionality in browsers. Plus such functionality is dying out and being replaced with zoom in/out. Whilst text-wrapping is a problem, I can't think of many scenarious in which you would want to vertical align a paragraph of text - vertical align used much more frequently for UI controls i.e. buttons.

Comment: @ChrisCannon Zooming text only is still possible in most browsers. In addition, that's not the only way user text preferences may affect text size (minimum font-size browser preferences, OS DPI settings, etc.) Even buttons may have multiple words that may wrap. In short, I consider using `line-height` to be a fragile method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find using the CSS display attribute `table-cell` the easiest method.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aQNWp/2/)

And the CSS:

```
div
{
    height:100px; /* or whatever % etc. */
    border: solid 1px black;
    vertical-align : middle; 
    display : table-cell;
}
```

Comment: @ChrisCannon Correct, [the table display methods are not supported in ie6/7](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

Comment: I no longer support them. I redirect IE6/7 to a page saying please update anyway. If they are still using them, they don't get to see my beautiful modern sites :P

Comment: I agree that people should get off IE6 definitely and also IE7 to a lesser extent. Unforetunetly I don't have that liberty :( some of my users still use IE7.